# Can we call Native Windows API from Delphi?

Tags: windows, delphi, winapi, delphi-7, system-calls

Is it possible to call the kernel Native APIs from within a Delphi application? Like `nt` and `zw` syscalls.

Comment: but we can call nt and zw syscalls in a usermode c/c++ program, they are not only for drivers

Comment: Formally you can write a driver in Delphi like in c/c++, there are no language limitations. The only practical problem is that delphi driver frameworks do not exist.

Comment: @Serg I'm not sure it's practical in Delphi to write a driver. How do you package the code up? Drivers aren't DLL or EXE files.

Comment: I thinks drivers are executables either, because they have PE header like other common executables.Serg is write, there is no limitation in writing drivers just in C/C++, there is lack of framework and header translation for delphi.

Comment: re Delphi drivers: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2263474/can-i-write-windows-drivers-with-delphi-2010

Comment: [Nt vs. Zw - Clearing Confusion On The Native API](http://www.osronline.com/custom.cfm?name=articlePrint.cfm&id=257)

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You can indeed call the native API from Delphi.

Delphi does not ship with header translations for the native API. So you need to provide your own, or use a pre-existing translation. For example. the JEDI translation of the NT API.

Comment: Exactly, you need JwaNative.pas from the Jedi Apilib (+1)

Answer (score 11):

As David Heffernan says it's perfectly possible to use the Native API from usermode and thus Delphi. You will need the JwaNative unit from the [Jedi Apilib](http://sourceforge.net/projects/jedi-apilib/).

Here is small example to enumerate processes using the Native API:
(TProcessList is a descendant from TObjectList but the relevant part is the call to NtQuerySystemInformation)

```
function EnumProcesses: TProcessList;
var
  Current: PSystemProcesses;
  SystemProcesses : PSystemProcesses;
  dwSize: DWORD;
  nts: NTSTATUS;
begin
  Result := TProcessList.Create;

  dwSize := 200000;
  SystemProcesses := AllocMem(dwSize);

  nts := NtQuerySystemInformation(SystemProcessesAndThreadsInformation,
      SystemProcesses, dwSize, @dwSize);

  while nts = STATUS_INFO_LENGTH_MISMATCH do
  begin
    ReAllocMem(SystemProcesses, dwSize);
    nts := NtQuerySystemInformation(SystemProcessesAndThreadsInformation,
      SystemProcesses, dwSize, @dwSize);
  end;

  if nts = STATUS_SUCCESS then
  begin
    Current := SystemProcesses;
    while True do
    begin
      Result.Add(TProcess.Create(Current^));
      if Current^.NextEntryDelta = 0 then
        Break;

      Current := PSYSTEM_PROCESSES(DWORD_PTR(Current) + Current^.NextEntryDelta);
    end;
  end;

  FreeMem(SystemProcesses);
end;
```

Comment: Are you an author of JwaNative?

Comment: Off-topic: Is it me, or is it really hard to find JEDI through websearch. Whenever I try, I always find loads of links to seemingly lots of different sites. And are there lots of different projects? Perhaps that's what confuses me.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan Project Jedi is fragmented but we share shortage on resources (hint)...

Comment: What resources are Jedi looking for?

Comment: Exactly we need tools that turn C headers into Delphi so we can definitely use both @DavidHeffernan and @WarrenP!

Comment: @Remko I'm sure I could translate a few C headers. Sounds like fun. The JEDI project that I'd quite like to get involved in is  `JclExprEval` mainly because I'm using it and found a few bugs and have some enhancement suggestions. I've reported them on the JEDI bug tracker but I suspect that code doesn't have an active maintainer. How could I go about getting involved?

Comment: @Remko I know this is an old thread but I really have to ask- what's the point in the Jedi projects when there are hardly any demos, documentation or even list of things I can use them for? Just nothing but the source? I read somewhere I could use Jedi to create a driver for virtual disk. Nothing more- no class name, no sample, nothing.

Comment: @Tom you mean demos [like this one](https://bitbucket.org/assarbad/objmgr-viewer/src/default/)? Perhaps your websearch-fu is weak? ;) ... there are actually plenty of samples out there. But it's true, JEDI *is a bloody mess*. It's badly fragmented and hard to find *the* information needed. This wasn't exactly better in Borland days, but at least it was *less* fragmented at the time. Also with JEDI we've seen lots of ideas in the past and little willingness to invest own time and effort. Of course I am speaking from experience about 15 years ago, so it may not be representative of today.

Comment: @0xC0000022L I asked this 5 years ago but thanks or an answer :D

Comment: @Tom: I know, which means I haven't touched Delphi 5 years longer than 5 years ago. Just thought it'd be nice to point you to sample code, you or future visitors may benefit from it.

Comment: Does anyone know of any examples of using JwaNative for Windows LPC ?